# Getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, enums

When I do the following:

```
configKeys = VALIDATION_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION.keys()
print(configKeys)
```

But when I do this:

```
keys = [ x.value for x in configKeys ]
```

I get the following error:

```
 keys = [ x.value for x in configKeys ]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Why is this so? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Most of those keys aren't members of your enum. They're just regular strings.

Comment: the `x`'s are strings, not keys.

Comment: What is `athena.enum.StrEnum`?

Comment: I put your question back to it's original state.  You edited out so much it was no longer a question and couldn't be answered.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over a dictionary yields its keys (which in your case are strings (`str` objects)). Strings don't have a `value` method or attribute.

If you want the values of your dict, you need to iterate over `VALIDATION_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION.values()` , or if you want both keys and values at the same time, `for (k, v) in VALIDATION_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION.items():`

Comment: Some of the keys are enum members, which do have a `value` attribute (making likely but not certain guesses about `athena.enum.StrEnum`).